# prove : if E(X) doesn't exist $E(x^2)$ too doesn't exist.

Tags: probability, statistics, expectation

$E(X^2) $ exists implies  $\int x^2  f_X(x) \ dx < \infty$

now from the property of Riemann Integral $\int|x|  f_X(x) \ dx \le  \int x^2  f_X(x) \ dx  $ . hence, existence of $E(X^2)$ implies existence of E(X) .

Is it right a right way to prove this ?

(i don't want a formal proof. I only want to know whether my logic is mathematical correct. actually i doubt that the property of Riemann integral that i have used is valid only for bounded functions. is it so ?

Comment: No, $\int|x|  f_X(x) \, dx <=  \int x^2  f_X(x) \, dx  $ is no guaranteed. What do you mean by "from the property of Riemann Integral"?

Comment: Square the LHS and you will be fine.

Comment: @GautamShenoy squaring LHS it would be fine , due to Cauchy-Schwartz inequality . right ?


thanks ..!


and talking about Riemann Integral... my inequality would be allowable had  the support of integration been bounded . right ? the support of integration is unbounded that's causing the difficulty ?

Comment: @Arnob: It is indeed due to Cauchy Schwarz. And as for your inequality, if you were to integrate restricted to $\{x:|x| \geq 1\}$, it would be fine.

Comment: @ArnobShamanta The reason why $E[|X|]\le E[X^2]$ doesn't hold is that $|x|>x^2$ whenever $0<|x|<1$. So boundness of the domain has nothing to do with that.

Comment: you mean this inequality over a semi closed or closed interval is valid ? 

or there's something special regarding the particular restriction  {x:|x|≥1} 
?

don't mind. may be i'm being too ignorant..!!

Comment: okay. i understand..:) @GautamShenoy..! thank you !

Comment: and thank you @G.Sassatelli too..:)

and one more thing. if f and g two function and h(x)>g(x) over entire real line. then then $\int h(x) f_X(x) \ dx>\int g(x)  f_X(x) \ dx$ holds always .even if the support is unbounded too . right ?

Answer (score 1):

If $E(X)$ doesn't exist, $E(X_+)$ or $E(X_-)$ or both are infinite. An application of the Jensen Inequality with the function $x^2$ will show you that $E(X^2) \geq E(X_+^2) \geq E(X_+)^2 = \infty$ (or the same calculation with $X_-$ if thats infinite).

Your calculation has the Problem, that not every random variable has to have a density.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the measure is the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$. Let $A$ be a non measurable set and let $X=1_A-1_{A^c}$. Then $X^2 = 1_{[0,1]}$. Hence $EX^2 = 1$ , but $EX$ does not even exist.

If you are using the Riemann integral, choose $A=[0,1]\cap \mathbb{Q}$ instead.

Comment: Presumably $X$ is supposed to be measurable.

Comment: @aes: Since the OP seems to be using the Riemann integral, take the second example which is measurable.

Comment: OP doesn't seem particularly concerned with (or careful about) such details. Typically in probability theory random variables are measurable functions. The Cauchy Schwarz or divided interval (which I'm partial to) proofs in the comments work nicely then.

Comment: @aes: If one ignores these details, the question is a little ill defined or has a chicken or the egg flavour.